# Angular 5 + Bootstrap Tooltip Not Working

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, angular5

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to get a [Bootstrap Tooltip](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/) to work in Angular 5. We have the Javascript library set up via the footer of the index.html page, as recommended. The documents on Bootstrap use JQuery to get ahold of the elements, then call the `tooltip()` function on them.

Thinking I might be able to do the same, but using the `getElementById` function to obtain a handle on the button, I wrote the following (the button is the item that has a tooltip defined on it):

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    let button = document.getElementById('tooltipBtn');
    button.tooltip();
  }
```

Template code (separate file):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom" id="tooltipBtn">
  Tooltip on bottom
</button>
```

The error I get (in the browser console):

```
ERROR
Error: button.tooltip is not a function
```

Comment: In your code, `button` is not a jQuery object, therefore the jQuery tooltip function is not available on it..... any jQuery functions like this have to be executed on the jQuery object, `$('#tooltipBtn').tooltip()`....

Comment: May I suggest you find, and use, an Angular-specific bootstrap library? Something like this: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples

Comment: @cale_b - our project didn't go that route, out of fear that the angular-specific library might diverge... but then again, should it really be necessary? Why shouldn't we be able to use the bootstrap code as-is?

Comment: OK. So that actually works, though the intellisense complains that it cannot find the name '$'. Post answer and I'll give credit where it's due :)

Comment: While I don't have a robust hard-and-fast-rule, the notion is that when you are in Angular, you use the "Angular way" to manipulate the DOM.  Introducing jQuery libraries to do that is redundant, and opens you up to conflicts.  Your point about "diverging" libraries is noted, but honestly about 50% of any Angular project is managing packages like this.  And - one data point that is useful when looking at libraries like this is to observe how many "GitHub stars" it has.  The ng-bootstrap library has over 5,300 which is actually a fairly impressive number.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, there are a few things that I had to do to get this to work properly.

**Angular.JSON** (Angular 6)

In this file, it is necessary to put in the Javascript and CSS links for bootstrap. The file used to be known as `.angular-cli.json` for previous versions, and it's one level deeper, so if you have that file, you'll need to make it `../node_modules`.  In any case, you'll have something like the following:

```
  "styles": [
   "src/styles.scss",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
   "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/popper.js",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ]
```

This will load the appropriate CSS and Javascript into your webpack, so that it will be globally accessible. *It's very important to load them in the correct order, as shown. Variations will fail.* More detailed instructions can be found [here](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-bootstrap/).

***.component.ts**

Within each of your components, to use the `$` operator, all you have to do is, at the top of the file, type

`declare var $;`

That's it. You won't get autocomplete, but the application will function when it's compiled.

**Working with other JS Libraries**

This also applies to, for example, lodash (the `_` operator) and many other Javascript libraries. It's also possible with many libraries to use, for example,

`import * as $ from 'jquery'` - however, for some reason, I have not found that to be reliable with the `jquery` library itself. It has worked for many others, including [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) and [`shortid`](https://github.com/dylang/shortid).

Comment: As per latest bootstrap, bundled JS files (`bootstrap.bundle.js` and minified `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`) include Popper, but not jQuery.
You can therefore include single `bootstrap.bundle.js` alongside `jquery.js` instead of separate popper.js

Answer (score 7):

You can use ng-bootstrap

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Import NgbModule in your app module

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; 

 imports: [
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
  ],
```

HTML:

```
 <button class="btn btn-secondary" placement="bottom" ngbTooltip="Tooltip Text..!!">
```

Comment: Yes, but if you need jquery for other things in your project, this path does not seem to work (at least, it didn't for me).